# Op-amp wrong output

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, pspice, orcad

I have imported a Spice model of an op-amp from the link below and tried to plot the same outputs, but I am getting different results.

Link to the Spice model I used and the desired plot: [https://www.eng.auburn.edu/~strouce/analogbc/opamp2.htm](https://www.eng.auburn.edu/%7Estrouce/analogbc/opamp2.htm)

Circuit I am using:

[image]

Output plots I am getting:

[image]

Edit: added a negative feedback and still getting the wrong results
[image]

Comment: You need some amount of negative feedback - otherwise, the circuit has no fixed bias point at the linear portion of the transfer curve. This is due to the huge open-loop gain of the opamp.

Comment: After looking at the netlist at the end I can see that the non-inverting terminal is connected to an AC source (Vin 17 0 AC 1 DC 0 sin(0 1 1Mhz) and the inverting terminal is connected to a resistor (R1 18 0 0) but the value of resistance here is given as 0. Also I did run simulation with a negative feedback but still didn't get the wanted results.

Comment: Anshul show us the circuit with feedback.

Comment: added in an edit section of original question

Comment: When you run ac simulations, you must *always* look at the operating bias point. It tells you if the dc levels are within the expected ballpark or not. Here, OrCAD should let you display the bias points and we could see if they are correct or not. If the op-amp is stuck to the upper or lower rail, then something is wrong. I would first simulate the raw netlist given in the page and check results are correct. Then, redo the exercise with the included .LIB and see it is still correct. If all is ok but OrCAD keeps giving wrong results, then the symbol pinout might be the issue.

Comment: Are you sure that "1" is the inverting terminal and "2" non-inverting? Supply voltages correct? What is the DC voltage at he output? Which signal voltage do you expext at the output?

Comment: @LvW yes I am sure about the pins as I have made a basic amplifier with the same pins and have obtained the correct results. I expect the Phase voltage and voltage in db in the output as same as the one shown in the link I have given in my question.

Comment: Spice file seems ok. Imported into microcap v12 and run it. No problem. I just had to add "AC" text on these lines:      .PLOT **AC** VDB(16) -50,50  ... and ...     .PLOT **AC** VP(16) -400,100

Comment: @Antonio51 can you replicate the same plots given in the link?

Comment: Allready done. See answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For finding the open-loop curve, you should use "special" feedback.
For reference, Example with a "classic" op-amp.

[image]

For closed-loop, with one resistor your feedback is ok.
Probably, "operating point" check in your simulator.

NB: your generator amplitude voltage too high in TRAN analysis.

You can do also a DC Analysis if you want see the "characteristic" curve (Vout versus Vin).
See the "open-loop gain" under "slope" in the picture.

[image]

After "import" of the Spice file (free simulator [microcap v12](http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/mc12cd.zip)), I have this picture which seems "ok".
As pointed out by @Verbal Kint, probably pinout issue.

[image]